# MySQL DB Offline/Online with Java Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, offline-caching

I have to make project using Java with Hibernate and MySQL database.
Server with Database is in main office.

Company has several buildings and magazines across country and they want to operate on that database.

Some of this magazines very often doesn't have internet connection, but they still should be able to edit some data and when computer connects to internet this edited should go to server and also update from current server state.

I got some ideas but don't know if they good and how exactly done them.

- First one was to save SQL queries from client and execute them when going online.
- Second one was to have local database which will sync with online server, but this is problem that I have only basic idea on databases.

I've heard something about database replication, but don't know how to make it with hibernate.

Do you have any better ideas?